# Android, waiting dialog not showing at all

Tags: android, dialog

I want to show the waiting dialog but it doesn't show at all, which is weird because the thing that takes a lot of time is the setData() function where i get a json feed and I save them in database (it takes 3/5 seconds).

Here is my code :

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TabLayoutActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

    //refresh the view
    taskLiteApplication.setData();

    //change view
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(TabLayoutActivity.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
    TabLayoutActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    //kill the dialog waiting
    dialog.cancel();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the issue is the fact that you are doing the all of this work on the UI thread, so the moment you start the dialog, the thread that starts and shows the window is actually freezing while you do the setData() work. You really should move the setData function to a background thread or a AsyncTask so that the UI thread can continue while you do the heavy work in the background.

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

void doStuff()
{
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TabLayoutActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    HeavyTask task = new HeavyTask();
    task.execute();
}

private class HeavyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
         //refresh the view
         taskLiteApplication.setData();
         return;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void results) {
         //change view
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(TabLayoutActivity.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
         TabLayoutActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

         //kill the dialog waiting
         dialog.dismiss();
         dialog = null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes it's probably that i was thinking that launching the dialog before would be fine but yes,

Comment: I'll try to do this in an asynctask then i'll keep you updated thanks for your answer

Comment: Working, you just missed the return in the doInBackground function, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing taskLiteApplication.setData(); is operating in the UI thread instead of a background thread or it's operating in a background thread and the cancel is being called because it's cancelling in the UI thread.

Basic thread to fix your issue:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog; // Keep this global
private Handler mHandler;

void doStuff() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TabLayoutActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...",  true);
    mHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.obj != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //change view
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(TabLayoutActivity.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
                TabLayoutActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    };
    //refresh the view
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // Assuming setData does NOT run on it's own background thread
            taskLiteApplication.setData();
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            message.obj = "DONERAEREAR";
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    })};
    t.start();
}
```

**EDIT** Added a handler, as pointed out by Wizetux the dialog needs to be cancelled in the UI thread

The benefit of this is you can send the handler error messages, warning messages, sucess messages and handle accordingly.

E.G.

```
message.obj = "ERROR";
mHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

then in the handler

```
if ((String)msg.obj.equals("ERROR")) { /* Handle Error */ }
```

Comment: You can not call the dialog.cancel from the background thread. It must be done from the UI thread. This won't work as is.